# Can RabbitMQ used in a Python consumer (via pika) have race conditions between concurrently received messages?

Tags: python, concurrency, rabbitmq, race-condition, pika

Suppose we have the following simple RabbitMQ callback logic in Python:

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', 5672, '/', pika.PlainCredentials("user", "password")))
channel = connection.channel()

msg_count = 0

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    global msg_count
    msg_count += 1
    print("Received %i messages" % msg_count)

channel.basic_consume(queue="my_queue", on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
```

If a producer sends two messages practically at the same time, is it possible that "Received 1 messages" will be printed twice due to a race condition?

I'm just not sure how these callbacks run - are they run concurrently?  In a thread?  Some other way?

Comment: Generally yes, but it depends on the connection adapter and the code used. A BlockingConnection reduces the risk. See the [docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html) for details!

Comment: @KlausD. Can I eliminate this risk by using `for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume('test'): <handle body here>` instead of the callback method above?  If so, what are the costs?

Comment: If you are afraid of race conditions, use a [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#lock-objects). (See the bottom of the page as well!)

Comment: @KlausD So what exactly happens when a message is received when there's a callback registered via `channel.basic_consume()`?  Does a new thread get created to run the callback?  I don't see an explanation in the [`basic_consume()` docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.basic_consume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a producer sends two messages practically at the same time, is it
> possible that "Received 1 messages" will be printed twice due to a
> race condition?

No. Pika runs an I/O loop internally and events are dealt with as they are ready, sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, so basically, `callback()` will get called once the first message is fully received, then that call will be processed, and only once it is completed, will the next message be processed?  I suppose there's no concern of the next message "expiring" if the first callback call takes too long?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "expiring". Stack Overflow is really not the best place for an extended discussion of Pika. Please ask further questions on the [Pika mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pika-python).